# AbstractMethodError org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.supportsSourceType with Spring boot 2.2.1

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to setup a Spring cloud stream project with Spring boot starter 2.2.1,  spring cloud version Hoxton and cloud stream version 3.0.0.

Below is my pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>

    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <kotlin.version>1.3.61</kotlin.version>
    </properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

When I run the application,I see

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.supportsSourceType(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z at org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.supportsSourceType(GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.java:81)
   ...
```

I found out that [the same error](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16158) is thrown while migrating from spring boot 2.0.5 to 2.1.1 and due to dependency mismatch.

In my case, I believe that I am using the right release train versions of Spring boot and [Spring cloud](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream) and this `pom.xml` is generated by spring initializr.

However, I tried upgrading spring-core to 5.2.1.release, as the default spring-core (version 5.0.5)threw this error => `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize` and this class is introduced in 5.2.1.

Has anyone come across this error with Spring boot 2.2.1 ? Any input is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: 5.0.5 isn't the default Spring Framework version for Spring Boot 2.2 so it sounds like something's wrong with your dependency management. The pom you've shared gives me 5.2.1.RELEASE of `spring-core` even without the explicit dependency on it. Can you please share your complete `pom.xml` and the output from `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: Also, I don't see you using spring-cloud-stream, You have `spring-cloud-stream` dependency but I do not see any binder. Please follow the [Quick Start](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.0.RC1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_quick_start) section.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson There are tons of entries in my dependency management section. I will create a new maven project and try this.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky I am trying to use spring integration way instead of using binder